# CMD Batch - Search for last occurence of character while looping through file

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

I have a .txt file which I loop through every line and spool to another file. Ok no problem so far. But I want NOT to spool lines, which have following criteria:

they contain more slashes. Find the last slash. After this one search the rest of the string for .*** (* = wildcard). If not found don´t spool, else spool.

Input file content for example:

```
c:/abc/abc/
c:/abc/abc/test.txt
c:/eee/
c:/eee/test.cfg
c:/test/abc/test/xxx/bbb/ccc/aaa/test.txt
c:/test/abc/test/xxx/bbb/ccc/aaa/
```

Output should look like:

```
c:/abc/abc/test.txt
c:/eee/test.cfg
c:/test/abc/test/xxx/bbb/ccc/aaa/test.txt
```

It is not static, where this lines appear, which should be removed. So I thought about finding the last slash and take all after that and look if there the last thing is ".***" If so keep else don´t echo

I don´t want to use other tools for this. It must be done via native command-line functionality.

Maybe somebody can help me out.

Code:

```
 >OUTPUT.txt (
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN ("FILE.txt") DO (
set "line=%%I"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem DO SOMEHTING HERE I DON`T KNOW HOW TO DO
echo(!line!)
)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do it in one line using `findstr` and its regular expression mode (`\....$` means all strings ending with `.` followed by 3 characters):

```
findstr /R \....$ FILE.txt
```

result:

```
c:/abc/abc/test.txt
c:/eee/test.cfg
c:/test/abc/test/xxx/bbb/ccc/aaa/test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice solution. What if I don´t have slashes at the end? Then i thought to take the string after the last slash and look if it contains .***   . How can i achieve that ?

Comment: I misread your question. I have edited my answer. Result is identical of course :)